# My unordered list disappears when I add overflow-y

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I was messing around with overflows and I noticed that my list disappeared when I created the top-wrapper for my code.

```css
body {
    font-size: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Arial";
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
}
li:hover {
    color: red;
}
h1,h2 {
    color: lightcoral;
}
.left,.right {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.top-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.top-menu {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height: 30px;
}
.sub-top-l,.sub-top-r {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px
}
.sub-top-l {
    float: left;
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.sub-top-r {
    float: right;
    background-color: darkred;
}
.list-wrap {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <h1>Cowabunga</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="top-wrapper">
            <div class="top-menu">

            </div>
            <div class="sub-top-l">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="sub-top-r">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-wrap">
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only way to get the list to show is to add the display property absolute to the CSS class `.top-wrapper`.

Does anyone know why this is the default behavior? I'm looking for a detailed explanation.

[JSFfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u8yqecdm/)

Add `position: absolute` to `.top-wrapper` to get it to show.

Comment: You can also get the list to show by using `overflow-y: visible;`

Comment: and does removing the top-wrapper and all of the child elements. I still haven't figured out why tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't write up a great/detailed explanation at the moment, but long story short, it's because of how floats work (they are positioned in the normal flow and then moved out of it in order to float against the furthest edge in their specified direction) and because you haven't cleared the element that is the sibling to the floated elements, the `.list-wrap` div.

Clearing an element will tell the next element in line (in this case, `.list-wrap` to move to a new line rather than try to wrap around the floated element.

`position: absolute;` works because that tells an element to display, absolutely, wherever you tell it to, relative to the nearest `position: relative;` ancestor (if there is one).

Here's a minimal demo with that element cleared:

```css
.right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.sub-top-l, .sub-top-r {
    width: 50%;
}
.sub-top-l {
    float: left;
}
.sub-top-r {
    float: right;
}
.list-wrap {
    overflow-y: auto;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="top-wrapper">
            <div class="sub-top-l">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="sub-top-r">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-wrap">
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's a demo of your page with that element cleared:

```css
body {
    font-size: 36px;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Arial";
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
}
li:hover {
    color: red;
}
h1,h2 {
    color: lightcoral;
}
.left,.right {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.top-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.top-menu {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    height: 30px;
}
.sub-top-l,.sub-top-r {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px
}
.sub-top-l {
    float: left;
    background-color: darkblue;
}
.sub-top-r {
    float: right;
    background-color: darkred;
}
.list-wrap {
    overflow-y: auto;
    clear: left;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <h1>Cowabunga</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="top-wrapper">
            <div class="top-menu">

            </div>
            <div class="sub-top-l">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="sub-top-r">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="list-wrap">
            <ul>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
                <li>test</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to read more on floats and clears and get a more detailed answer. But this sufficed. Thanks again.

Comment: Also... after learning more about floats and clears I realized I could make the list-wrap into an inline-block element and that would work too.